# A generator for refactoring a combination of for loops and nested if statements

Tags: python, refactoring, generator

The next code scans some log file and selects the lines with some particular characters.

```
with open(file) as input:
    for line in input:
        if 'REW' in line or 'LOSE' in line:
            <some optional code>
            if 'REW VAL' in line or 'LOSE INV' in line:
                <some code>
```

I wrote some functions upon this but every function contains this repeated code, so I think refactoring is needed. And I guess I need to make a generator. How do I make this generator that will allow me to change the code in brackets?

Comment: *so I think refactoring is needed. And I guess I need to make a generator* What exactly are you up to?

Comment: Why don't you simply make the repeated code a function, so you can call the function instead ???

Comment: How you refactor this depends very much on what the bracketed code can do. (Does it use `return`, `continue`, `break` or `yield`?)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Just don't want to paste the exact same code in every function that counts some values upon scanned lines of file.

Comment: @coder I really wish to know how to make that function.

Comment: @chepner The code in brackets may look like `total += 1`. Every time I rather tend to wrap the above code in a function and I don't escape repetition.

Comment: If the code processes a file, you could create a general function that takes a  file as input and returns the appropriate processed file as output. With the info you provide I can't help you any further - write a sample function I mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes repetition is not that bad!

But anyway you can try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# script.py

def process_file(filename, func1, func2):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if '1' in line:
                func1(line)
                if '2' in line:
                    func2(line)


def main():
    counters = {1: 0, 2: 0}
    def func1(line):
        # TODO Add some logic based on line value here
        counters[1] += 1
    def func2(line):
        counters[2] += 1
    process_file('table.csv', func1, func2)
    return counters


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

And if you have a file:

```
$ cat table.csv
1 just one
1 2 one and two
1
1
0
0
2
2 1
1 0 2
0
```

And run the script:

```
python script.py
```

You will get the next output:

```
{1: 6, 2: 3}
```

Also you can factor out predicates of your `if` statements:

```
def process_file(filename, func1, func2, predicate1, predicate2):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if predicate1(line):
                func1(line)
                if predicate2(line):
                    func2(line)

def predicate1(line):
    return 'REW' in line or 'LOSE' in line
```

Don't forget to choose nice function names!

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary code, the best you can do is write a function like

```
def foo(file, f1, f2):
    with open(file) as input:
        for line in input:
            if 'REW' in line or 'LOSE' in line:
                f1(line)
                if 'REW VAL' in line or 'LOSE INV' in line:
                    f2(line)
```

where you need to impose some condition on how `f1` and `f2` are called (here, I define them as functions that take a line as input).

This isn't fully general, though. For instance, the function `f1` can't decide to skip the next `if` statement and continue to the next line from the file.